# Configure react native workers for circle CI

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run a react native android build on circle ci
these are the react versions in package.json

"react": "^16.2.0",
 "react-native": "0.50.0",

I am setting these environment variables:

`_JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xmx2000m"
JVM_OPTS: "-Xmx2000m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1"
GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2000m"'
REACT_NATIVE_MAX_WORKERS: 1
NODE_ENV: "production"`

However it seems react still stars a lot of workers in the bundler and node fails with code 137, usually out of memory.

The way I managed to get it working was setting 
`nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node", "--max-old-space-size=200","--max_old_space_size=200"]`  , but it seems this works only after the build fails once and I run it again on the docker container.

Is there another config to limit react bundler workers? I feel like setting the memory to 200m would not be the best option.

[image: ps tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work, here is my config:

environment variables in config.yml

```
environment:
_JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xmx1600m -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:ParallelGCThreads=1 -XX:ConcGCThreads=1 -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process"
GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx1600m"'
REACT_NATIVE_MAX_WORKERS: 1
NODE_ENV: "production"
NODE_OPTIONS: "--max-old-space-size=500 --max_old_space_size=500"
```

and what I think fixed it:

```
app/build.gradle
....
project.ext.react = [
    extraPackagerArgs: ["--max-workers=1"]
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
...
```